# How to create a new category in the GNOME menu?

Tags: gnome

I want to create a custom category menu. How can I do that?

For example, I want to create a category menu named "Halogen" like Accessories, Games, Graphics, Internet..etc

Answer (score 6):

1. Need to write an XML `.menu` file to be installed in `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/`

   Example `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/hamradio.menu`

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/1.0/menu.dtd">
   <Menu>
     <Name>Applications</Name>
     <Menu>
       <Name>Hamradio</Name>
       <Directory>HamRadio.directory</Directory>
       <Include>
           <Category>HamRadio</Category>
       </Include>
     </Menu> <!-- End hamradio -->
   </Menu>
   ```
2. A `.directory` file to be install in `/usr/share/desktop-directories/`

   Example `/usr/share/desktop-directories/HamRadio.directory` (`[...]` I removed some lines)

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Directory
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Hamradio
   Name[bg]=Любителско радио
   Name[ca]=Radioaficionat
   Name[cs]=Amatérské rádio
   [...]
   Name[vi]=Truyền thành tài tử
   Name[zh_CN]=业余无线电
   Name[zh_TW]=業餘無線電
   Icon=CQ.png
   ```
3. Add category to `Categories=` in application `.desktop` file and should be install in `/usr/share/applications/`

Reference: [Freedesktop Menu Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html#adding-items)

Answer (score 1):

Based on info from http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/add-categories-to-gnome-shell-dashboard and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Using_GNOME/Application_menus

You need to open the dconf Editor (command dc)

From there navigate to org > gnome > shell 
You should see an entry called "app-folder-categories".
Double click on this and add/remove categories as you desire.

You can also use the gsettings tool

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.app-folder-categories
```

would should you the current categories and you can use the set command write a new value (which would be a comma separated list of your categories.

To place you software into the new category you will need to edit the .desktop launcher files located in /usr/share/applications/ . 
There should be one for each application, if you open one in your editor you should see an entry called "Categories" and you can add/remove categories (including the one you just created).

Comment: I actually wanted a command line method for making a deb file but what it  is said in the second link isn't working Making changes in Categories in .desktop file is not making any difference

Comment: Hi, might be worth mentioning this in the question to make it clearer that what you need is for packaging.

Comment: Everything needed is here:
https://developer.gnome.org/AppFolders/

Answer (score 1):

This extension should do what you want:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/